# Can a previously insignificant variable become significant in forward stepwise regression

Tags: r, logistic

I am doing forward stepwise logistic regression. I have heard that its common for a previously statistically significant variable to become not statistically significant when 1 or more variables is introduced into the model. However, I have never heard of the opposite. This is my case right now. The first variable selected was `x1` (by lowest p-value), the second variable selected was `x2`. What's interesting is that `x2` is not statistically significant when it is modeled with `Y` alone. I am using R to do this though, I think this more of statistics question.

Comment: Yes,easily. The big question is whether the calculated p-value is actually meaningful in the presence of variable selection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything can and will change when new variables are added to the model, the exception being when all the variables are orthogonal (think zero correlations). One way to see this is to imagine running a regression of y on x1 to get the residuals r1, and then regress those on x2 (which is exactly what multiple regression is doing). The variable r1 is fundamentally different from y, so you wouldn't expect the same inferences.

So this is kind of a dilemma, because you have as many answers to "Is x2 significant?" as regression models you can come up with. Forward selection is just one logical way to answer those questions, but there are many other ways, and the whole lot of them is pretty controversial.